# Initializing channel in function causing go routine deadlock

Tags: go

I am new to Go so I'm sure this is something simple I am missing. I am trying to initialize a channel to capture user input from another function. I tried the following:

```
package input

const UP = 1
const RIGHT = 2
const DOWN =3
const LEFT = 4

var inputChannel chan int

type InputReader interface {
  ReadNextInt() int
}

func InitInputChannel() chan int {
  inputChannel := make(chan int, 1)
  return inputChannel
}

func SendInput(inputReader InputReader) {
    inputChannel <- inputReader.ReadNextInt()
}
```

I then called the code with the following:

```
package input

import (
  "testing"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type MockedInputReader struct {
  mock.Mock
}

func (reader MockedInputReader) ReadNextInt() int {
  return 1
}

func TestShouldSendUpValueToChannelWhenUpKeyPressed(t *testing.T) {
  inputReader := new(MockedInputReader)
  inputReader.On("ReadNextInt").Return(UP)

  receiverChannel := SendInput(inputReader)

  actualInput := <- receiverChannel
  assert.Equal(t, UP, actualInput)
}
```

Looking at the code I just couldn't figure out the issue so I decided to restructure some things since I was getting desperate. I ended up with the following which worked:

```
package input

const UP = 1
const RIGHT = 2
const DOWN =3
const LEFT = 4

var inputChannel chan int = make(chan int, 1)

type InputReader interface {
  ReadNextInt() int
}

func SendInput(inputReader InputReader) chan int {
    inputChannel <- inputReader.ReadNextInt()
    return inputChannel
}
```

While I am glad that I got it working I am confused why my first solution didn't work. I am also not really crazy about returning my channel for every single SendInput call when it only needs grabbed once. Maybe a 'InputChannel() chan int' getter would be better? Any insight?  Thanks

Comment: The function InitInputChannel uses a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) to assign a channel to a local variable.  It looks like you were expecting to set the package-level variable instead. If so, use simple assignment instead of short variable declaration.

Comment: @ThunderCat Ahhhhh I can't believe it was so simple. Well this is at least a lesson I won't forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ThunderCat mentioned in the comments on my question, I was using the incorrect form of variable declaration. So I should have done something like this:

```
package input

const UP = 1
const RIGHT = 2
const DOWN = 3
const LEFT = 4

var inputChannel chan int

type InputReader interface {
    ReadNextInt() int
}

func InitChan() chan int {
  inputChannel = make(chan int, 1)
  return inputChannel
}

func SendInput(inputReader InputReader) {
    inputChannel <- inputReader.ReadNextInt()
}
```

The key to notice is the '***inputChannel = make(.....)***' rather than '***inputChannel := make(....)***' like I was trying before.